# How should 'conventional' Ember-friendly APIs be designed for creation of mutually dependent parent and child models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data, restful-architecture

I'm building a Rails app with an Ember front-end. I'm trying hard to ensure that the API is as plain, vanilla, RESTful and conventional as possible, in the Rails/Ember spirit.

I'm confused as to how to handle a situation where a parent model requires at least one child, and child models all require the existence of the parent.

Here's a somewhat contrived example:

```
class Meal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :appetizer
  has_one :entree
  has_many :side_dishes
  has_many :desserts

  # ensures there is AT LEAST one appetizer, entree, side dish or dessert
  validate :plate_is_not_empty

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :appetizer, :entree, :side_dishes, :desserts
end

class Appetizer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :meal
  validates_presence_of :meal
end

class Entree < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :meal
  validates_presence_of :meal
end

class SideDish < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :meal
  validates_presence_of :meal  
end

class Dessert < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :meal
  validates_presence_of :meal
end
```

In the past (aka pre-Ember, with a standard Rails app), my path was always to create the parent object through the parent controller (would have been MealsController, in this case), with at least one nested child.

```
snack = Meal.create(:name => 'Late night snack', :side_dishes_attributes => {:name => 'Corn Bread'})
```

then I was free to tack on additional children as needed, later on, as the parent had already been created.

```
Dessert.create(:name => "Marshmellow Fluff straight from the jar", :meal => snack)
```

But what's the best way to handle a situation like this with Ember? I'm assuming it's just a special case that'll require a custom ajax call with the nested attributes, which is fine. But I'm wondering how a situation like this fits into the emerging API standards that Ember is advocating. (And of which I'm a big fan.)

Comment: If you embed your child record, then you can keep your approach (I don't see anything wrong about it).

Comment: good enough for me. thanks.

Comment: You can read this blog post to know where ember data is heading http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/05/03/ember-data-progress-update.html